Lottie interactivity frames action doesnt work
i want to animate an hamburger menu, the problem is that when i click on the dottie files the animation is complete, not respecting the frames i selected in the script
HTML:
    <dotlottie-player id="polp" src="https://lottie.host/c8921211-86fe-4265-b84e-74834ba6831b/gywO1u8Efd.json" background="transparent" speed="1" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></dotlottie-player>





    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@dotlottie/player-component@latest/dist/dotlottie-player.mjs" type="module"></script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-interactivity@latest/dist/lottie-interactivity.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

SCRIPT.JS
const svgm = document.getElementById('polp');

svgm.addEventListener('ready',() => {
    LottieInteractivity.create({
        player: svgm.getLottie(),
        mode:"cursor",
        actions: [
            {
                
                visibility: [0,1],
                type: "click",
                forceFlag: false,
                frames: [0,42],
            }
        ]
        });
    });

I want to animate the lottie file correctly, respecting frames i selected
